# Can you do move_uploaded_file by $_FILES['name'] instead of $_FILES['tmp_name'] in php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to loop through an array of variables of type '$_FILES' posted from a form and process each image and store directories

The code is

```
if(isset($_POST['travsubli'])){

$date=Date('Y-m-d');
$uname=substr($utravlastname,0,5).substr($utravphone,5,10);
$destin=str_replace(array(" ","/","."),"-",$_POST['Destination']);
if(!is_dir("images/userimages/travelphotos")) {mkdir("images/userimages/travelphotos");}
if(!is_dir("images/userimages/travelphotos/$uname")){mkdir("images/userimages/travelphotos/$uname");}
echo "Check : ".$_FILES['TourPhoto1']['name']."<br>";
$photosarray=array($_FILES['TourPhoto1']['name'],$_FILES['TourPhoto2']['name'],$_FILES['TourPhoto3']['name'],$_FILES['TourPhoto4']['name'],$_FILES['TourPhoto5']['name'],$_FILES['TourPhoto6']['name']);

$pai=1;
foreach($photosarray as $pha){
$ext=pathinfo($pha,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!empty($ext)){

$newphotoname="Travelogue-Photo-$destin-$pai.$ext";
$newphotopath="images/userimages/travelphotos/$uname/$newphotoname";

      if(move_uploaded_file($pha,$newphotopath)){
           echo "Photo Successfully Uploaded !<br>";
        }else{echo "Something went wrong with Photo Upload !<br>";     $e=error_get_last();echo $e['message']."<br>";}
       }    
$TourPhoto="TourPhoto$pai";
$$TourPhoto=$newphotoname;
echo $pha."->$TourPhoto->".$$TourPhoto.$pai."<br>";
$pai++;  
}
```

My question or rather propblem is,

Move_uploaded_file does not work.

I presume it is because I am using $_FILES['variable']['name'] instead of $_FILES['variable']['tmp_name'] in the move_uploaded_file command.

Am I right in my diagnosis ? If so, what should be done ? Because, I have assigned 'name' parameter in the array to loop. How do I undo it to 'tmp_name' inside the loop ? Or is there any other better alternative ?

Comment: WHy can't you just use `tmp_name`?

Comment: @u_mulder If I use tmp_name, i cannot get the actual extension of the file. It gives .tmp

Comment: Then combine both fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what real problem is but you can try this:

```
$photosarray = array( 
    array(
        'tmp_name' => $_FILES['TourPhoto1']['tmp_name'],
        'real_name' => $_FILES['TourPhoto1']['name'],
    ),
    array(
        'tmp_name' => $_FILES['TourPhoto2']['tmp_name'],
        'real_name' => $_FILES['TourPhoto2']['name'],
    ),
    array(
        'tmp_name' => $_FILES['TourPhoto3']['tmp_name'],
        'real_name' => $_FILES['TourPhoto3']['name'],
    ),
    // etc
);

foreach ($photosarray as $pha) {
    $ext = pathinfo($pha['real_name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $path = ''; 
    // make your path here

    // copy file
    move_uploaded_file($pha['tmp_name'], $new_path);
    // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: you are a genius ! Because you actually understood my problem and saved my day ! Thanks a ton !